# xdebug not picking up http request

Tags: php, ubuntu, netbeans, vps

I have moved to a new VPS (this vps will only run one site) and am unable to connect to my project with netbeans to debug it and I get the infuriating 'Waiting for connection' message. I am running out of ideas. Here are the steps I took for the ubuntu 12.04 LTS server I am running. It has plesk running on it as well.

So I installed xdebug with apt-get 
I then put my phpinfo into the [xdebug wizard](http://xdebug.org/wizard.php) and upgraded to 2.2.4
I verified that xdebug is installed properly and restarted apache and in my phpinfo I can see xdebug there.
I set the following in the xdebug.ini

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_mode = “req”
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.idekey = “netbeans-xdebug”
xdebug.remote_log = "/tmp/new_xdebug_remote.log"
```

I also opened port 9000 with ufw and here is the output

```
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 2] 80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 3] 22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 4] 9000/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 5] 443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[ 6] 80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[ 7] 22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[ 8] 9000/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

NOTE: I have also tried with just 9000 not 9000/tcp

My netbeans is setup properly as the test connection is good and apart from the ip address it is the same as my previous setup to my previous AWS ec2 instance.

The port forwarding is working as I tested it with the AWS setup which works a treat. I need to debug this new VPS as I have seen an issue here not seen on AWS which is a real kick in the balls.

The xdebug log is not generated in the /tmp directory as it should be. This is suggesting to me that xdebug is never started as it does not receive the request.

Here are my xdebug settings as well incase they are needed:

```
xdebug support  enabled
Version 2.2.4
IDE Key “netbeans-xdebug”

Supported protocols Revision
DBGp - Common DeBuGger Protocol $Revision: 1.145 $

Directive   Local Value Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace   Off Off
xdebug.cli_color    0   0
xdebug.collect_assignments  Off Off
xdebug.collect_includes On  On
xdebug.collect_params   0   0
xdebug.collect_return   Off Off
xdebug.collect_vars Off Off
xdebug.coverage_enable  On  On
xdebug.default_enable   On  On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.ENV no value    no value
xdebug.dump.FILES   no value    no value
xdebug.dump.GET no value    no value
xdebug.dump.POST    no value    no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION no value    no value
xdebug.dump_globals On  On
xdebug.dump_once    On  On
xdebug.dump_undefined   Off Off
xdebug.extended_info    On  On
xdebug.file_link_format no value    no value
xdebug.idekey   “netbeans-xdebug”   “netbeans-xdebug”
xdebug.max_nesting_level    100 100
xdebug.overload_var_dump    On  On
xdebug.profiler_aggregate   Off Off
xdebug.profiler_append  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_output_dir  /tmp    /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name cachegrind.out.%p   cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart Off Off
xdebug.remote_connect_back  On  On
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time    3600    3600
xdebug.remote_enable    On  On
xdebug.remote_handler   dbgp    dbgp
xdebug.remote_host  localhost   localhost
xdebug.remote_log   /tmp/new_xdebug_remote.log  /tmp/new_xdebug_remote.log
xdebug.remote_mode  “req”   “req”
xdebug.remote_port  9000    9000
xdebug.scream   Off Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_local_vars  Off Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta   Off Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger Off Off
xdebug.trace_format 0   0
xdebug.trace_options    0   0
xdebug.trace_output_dir /tmp    /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name    trace.%c    trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children 128 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data 512 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth    3   3
```

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are all those smart quotes (“req”) actually there?

Comment: probably as I copy and pasted it. looks the same as normal quotes in the file as I copied them stright out of my preivous xdebug.ini

Comment: F**K OFF I just tried that and you are correct! did not notice those at all! You sir are an eagle eyed legend

Answer (score 0):

As  @Álvaro G. Vicario noticed I had the wrong quotes around in my xdebug.ini and I had not noticed at all as I thought I copied it out of my previous xdebug.ini.